# Error using array in Activity

Tags: java, android, arrays, dictionary

I 'm building an Android app that fetches an XML-feed, parses it in different Objects(name, url, description) and saves those Objects to an Array.

All this happens in an FeedActivity, extending the Activity class.

Loading the xml and parsing to objects works fine, but each time I want to add an object to the Array, I'm getting an error on the

```
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityRecord,Intent) line:2494
```

I've also tried using a Map, but this had the same error.

Comment: Please post the code where you add the object to the error - and the error message, too.

Comment: When you examine your stack trace in LogCat, you will see a section prefixed with "Caused by" -- your code should appear in there. Also, please post the entire stack trace when asking questions on StackOverflow.